# Create Start Up SP that any time sql run, retrieval data base

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want Create Start Up Stored Procedure that, any time sql run 
retrieval Data Base. this is my code , Where i was wrong? Please help me.

```
USE MASTER
GO
CREATE PROC SP_RetrievalDataBase
AS
BEGIN
EXEC sp_detach_db 'AdventureWorks2012'
CREATE DATABASE MyAdventureWorks
ON
(FILENAME = 'G:\SQL Server 2012\AdventureWorks2012_Database\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf'),
(FILENAME = 'G:\SQL Server 2012\AdventureWorks2012_Database\AdventureWorks2012_Log.ldf')
    FOR ATTACH;
END
GO
EXEC sp_procoption 'SP_ReplaceDataBase', 'startup', '1'
```

Answer (score 2):

try setting your last parameter to 'ON' something like

```
EXECUTE sp_procoption 'SP_ReplaceDataBase', 'startup', 'on';
```

and use 'off' when you want the automatic execution, something like this

```
EXECUTE sp_procoption 'SP_ReplaceDataBase', 'startup', 'off';
```

**Warning** 
Please do not use `sp_` prefix for your procedure names, as Microsoft strongly recommends not using this prefix for you procedure names. the reason for this is as follows by Microsoft

> In SQL Server, the sp_ prefix designates system stored procedures. If
>   you use that prefix for your stored procedures, the name of your
>   procedure might conflict with the name of a system stored procedure
>   that will be created in the future. If such a conflict occurs, your
>   application might break if your application refers to the procedure
>   without qualifying the reference by schema. In this situation, the
>   name will bind to the system procedure instead of to your procedure.